# Compilation error - when adding private accessors to a C# unit test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, mstest, accessor

I have a C# project (wpf) in VS 2010.
I added a unit test project.
Everything was OK untill I've added private accessor to the project.

Now the unit tests project isn't compiling and I get the following error:

> collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute

Without any direction to a specific location.

Does anyone know what can be the reason?

Comment: We currently have no direction to a specific piece of code either, thus I'd kindly ask you to share the problematic code.

Comment: Show us the code where you use enumeration

Comment: Are you running TFS Explorer in VS? I have seen that error with it in VS2010, restarting VS is normally required.

Comment: You get that error when compiling? Not at runtime?

Comment: Hi, I don't have a code to show since there is no code!
I've just added a unittests project without adding any code, and created a private accessor. I have no idea which collection is the problematic one (if any) since the error message doesn't say anything but what I wrote above.
I'm using VS 2010 with TFS 2012 (I tried to restart the VS).
And yes - the error is in COMPILE time (NOT run time).

any ideas?

Comment: There's not a lot of context here but 'collection was modified' invariably comes with a stack trace that tells you the file name and line number of a loop that modifies the items the loop is enumerating.